# Postgresql 9.5 allow remote connections without editing pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I want to allow remote connections in my Postgresql version 9.5 without editing pg_hba.conf file, is it possible ?
thanks

Comment: Nope.   pg_hba.conf is mandatory configuration.

Comment: i want a sql server in order to connect remotely to database from other machines, do u know an other server that connect remotely without configuring, because i want to facilitate installing to customer.

Comment: why is editing `pg_hba.conf` not an option? You could create one that allows connections from anywhere with a password and then distribute that with your installation.

Comment: Because i am working with ana application that i'll sell it to lot of persons, & i want to facilitate the work, it means i don't want to make these persons enter to this file & edit it...

Comment: Consider dockerizing, using a VFS, or using an embeddable RDBMS instead.